# Node TypeError - "not a function" on require()'d class method

Tags: node.js

I have the following class:

```
const exec = require('child_process').execSync;

class Git {

    static branchExists (branchNameToCheck) {
        return ( exec(`git rev-parse --verify --quiet ${branchNameToCheck} > /dev/null`).length > 0 );
    }

}

module.export = Git;
```

This is called in the following (simplified) script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const Git = require('./classes/Git');

if (Git.branchExists('develop')) console.log('success');
```

I get the following error:

```
Git.branchExists();
    ^

TypeError: Git.branchExists is not a function
```

Why is it not recognising `branchExists` as a function? When I run `console.log(Git)` I get `{}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it may just be a typo: `module.export = Git;` -> `module.exports = Git;`. If you don't define module.exports, the imported object ("Git" in this case) will be an empty object https://stackabuse.com/how-to-use-module-exports-in-node-js/